# New Firebase 9 Android sdk gives "Invalid Idp response" after some time

Tags: android, sdk, firebase

I am implementing the new Firebase 9 sdk for Android.

I have a token that works fine for some  time. But suddnetly (after some time) it starts giving me this error:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Invalid Idp Response: uTiiuHJhgtt514rEeqwqevavasvastastasbYASYStskASmASolASoASouAHASbnASASbhAStfA (THAT STRING IS HUUUUUGE).]
```

What should I do when I get this error? On the old SDK I dispatched a service in background that get a new token. But with this new SDK I should call the google activity intent for a login which is pretty bad for user experience.

Comment: I get the same issue : I fails on firebaseAuthWithGoogle() ->task.isSuccessful() return false. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: I guess you are migrating your old project to new sdk. Please give more info and the relevant code where it fails (for ex.during login)

Comment: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response: ] at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafd.zzes(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafa$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafl.zzet(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafl$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Comment: It fails at  step:4 firebaseAuthWithGoogle() from  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin
above is the possible trace.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your web application client ids correlate between the Google API console and what is registered in the Firebase console.  The web application client ID would be one with authorized Javascript origins including https://[YOUR_APP_ID].firebaseapp.com (usually generated automatically in Google API and registered in Firebase console).  Make sure this is the web client id passed to the GoogleSignInOptions object when requesting ID token.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/d9MHQjAxFBY